# Python (win10): python35.dll and VCRUNTIME140.dll missing

Tags: python, dll, command-line

I have installed `WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.2Qt5` 
I try to access Python from the command line. It accesses the `symlink`

```
C:\Users\usr>where python
C:\Windows\System32\python.exe
```

when I execute

```
C:\Users\usr>python
```

I got the error:

> The program can't start because VCRUNTIME140.dll is missing from your
>   computer. Try reinstalling to fix this problem The program can't start
>   because python35.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling
>   to fix this problem

if I execute

```
C:\Users\usr\Documents\MyExes\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.2Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\python.exe
```

everything runs smoothly

what can I do to call Python simply by python instead of `python_path\python`?

Comment: add `python exe` path to `Environmental variable path` [link](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables)

Answer (score 0):

Add the path to Environment variable , This may help you : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5MchIy7r1o

This is download linkt to fix VCRUNTIME140.dll missing error: http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/4/1/041224F6-A7DC-486B-BD66-BCAAF74B6919/vc_redist.x86.exe

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help

I discovered that executing 
C:\Windows\System32\python.exe
just doesn't work

so I just erased python.exe symlink in the system32 folder
and added 
C:\Users\usr\Documents\MyExes\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.2Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\
to PATH

and it works

Thank you again !!!